# Inserting into database but they are integers instead of strings and leading zeros I want to have vanish

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert into a table that I created in sqlite3 using python 3.9

```py
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE name(id INTEGER, number TEXT, othernumber TEXT, morenumber INTEGER DEFAULT 0);')

conn.commit()
```

Then when I try to insert a string from python that contains a leading 0, for example

```py
cur.execute('INSERT INTO name VALUES({}, {}, {}, {});'.format(0, "0123", "034", 23)

conn.commit()
```

and then I query to see the tables and I get

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM name')

data = cur.fetchall()

print(data)
```

I get  `[(0, '123', '34', 23)]`

missing the starting zeros. I checked if the columns had the right type and it says its TEXT.

Comment: Use parameter substitution for the values as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3).  Using string formatting for values is not safe.  In this case, the values aren't being quoted correctly so they are interpreted as ints.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement is formatted into this string:

```sql
INSERT INTO name VALUES(0, 0123, 034, 23);
```

Since the values aren't quoted, they are interpreted as numbers and the leading zeroes are omitted before they are converted to `text`. You could treat them as string by quoting them...

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO name VALUES({}, '{}', '{}', {});".format(0, "0123", "034", 23)
# Here ----------------------------------^--^--^--^
```

... but that's probably not the best idea.

A more robust idea would be to stop relying on string formatting and use bind variables:

```py
cur.execute('INSERT INTO name VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);', (0, "0123", "034", 23))
```

Comment: oh thank you such a dumb mistake yea thats the problem when i pass it into a f string as a string it omits the " thank you so much